# how to add face time in iOS4 app?

Tags: ios, facetime

Is there an API which I can use to integrate face time in my app?

Didn't find anything on google :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the time being, the only thing you can do with Facetime is initiating calls with URLs:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: whats the "+123456789"?? phone number?

Comment: Yeah, just an example phone number.

Comment: can I get phone number programatically? is it allowed by apple?

Comment: and what about iPod touch? I think face time is also supported on iPod touch 4G. How do these devices have phone number?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the contacts, look for "Address Book Programming Guide for iOS" in the documentation. The only number that you can't extract is the phone owner. iPods, although they're not phones, still have Address Books.

Comment: ok.. I got that I can call on phone numbers but confuse on iPod touch... Can I not call iPod touch to iPod touch using  face time? because iPods dont have phone number. can you please explain this a little  bit more.. will be appreciated... thanks..

Comment: You don't actually need phone numbers to make facetime calls. iPod to iPod, or iPod to Mac work just fine because they register with an email, they're still contacts. Though, I never tried the URL "facetime://xx" with anything but phone numbers.